# How to prevent CKEditor from changing tag order

Tags: ckeditor

CKEditor transforms the following code :

```
<h3>H3  
<ul>
    <li>el 1</li>
    <li>el 2</li>
</ul></h3>
```

to

```
    <h3>H3  </h3> 
<ul>
    <li>el 1</li>
    <li>el 2</li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: I made a few experiments with http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-protectedSource, Maybe you can configure CKEditor so it ignores some code based on regular expressions. It is meant to "protect" e.g. PHP code, but maybe it can be used to avoid that it changes some HTML code as well? In my tests it did not exactly work, but that might be due to the regex expression that was not accurate.

Comment: Hi Matthias and thank you! I only use CKEditor. I am not allowed to configure the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TL;DR; **no**

CKEditor is an HTML4/xHTML editor and is based on DTD, which gives a complete set of rules regarding which tags are available and where/how they can appear inside the DOM.

If you will check the [`DTD`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html) you can see that `H3` is a `heading` tag (which is a `block`) that can have only inline tags inside.

```
<!ENTITY % heading "h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6">
....
<!ENTITY % block
"p | %heading; | div | %lists; | %blocktext; | isindex |fieldset | table">
....
<!ELEMENT h3 %Inline;>
<!ATTLIST h3
    %attrs;
    %TextAlign;
>
```

The `ul` tag is also a `block` tag, so it can't appear inside `h3` tag:

```
<!ENTITY % lists "ul | ol | dl | menu | dir">
....
<!ENTITY % block
"p | %heading; | div | %lists; | %blocktext; | isindex |fieldset | table">
```

Comment: Unfortunately I only assume(and don't check) that CKEditor is HTML5 editor. Thanks!